# Getting Data from Server side HTTP.call to Client template

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I currently use meteor for a microproject of mine to get a bit usage experience with it. Shortly after setting up I ran into some trouble getting Data i recieve from an API call to a third party site to the client into the template. I checked the usual places for answers and found some information but nothing seems to get it working for me.

So I have a simple API Call to the Steam Web Api:

```
Meteor.methods({
  getPlayerStats: function() {
    return HTTP.get("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&steamid=XXXXXXXX");
  }
});
```

(Api key and steam id removed for anonymity purpose, but the call indeed returns a valid response)

So I use Iron Router for template rendering.

```
Router.route('/profile/:steamid', {
  name:'profile',
  template: 'profile',
  data: function() {
    Meteor.call('getPlayerStats', function(err, res) {
      if(err) {
        return {err: err, stat: null};
      } else {
        var redata = JSON.parse(res.content);
        var stats = redata.playerstats.stats;
        console.log({err: null, stats: stats});
        return {err: null, stats: stats};
      }
    });
  }
});
```

So as you can see i return an object in the data method containing either err or a parsed version of the result i get from the api call. The console.log actually returns everything as intended in the client browser, that is an object like this:

```
{err: null, stats: [{name: "xx", value: "XY"},...]}
```

And now the part that actually gets me wondering, the template:

```
<template name="profile">
  <p>{{err}}</p>
  <ul>
    {{#each stats}}
      <li>{{name}} - {{value}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

Which fails to render anything, not the err (which is null and therefor not very important) but neither the stats array.

Anyone has any idea where I went wrong on this one?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return data from asynchronous call. Instead, You can do it in the template's created function by using `ReactiveVar` or `Session Variable` like this

```
Template.profile.created = function () {
// or Template.profile.onCreated(function () {
    var template = this;
    template.externalData = new ReactiveVar(null);
    Meteor.call('getPlayerStats', function(err, res) {
        if(err) {
            template.externalData.set({err: err, stat: null});
        } else {
            var redata = JSON.parse(res.content);
            var stats = redata.playerstats.stats;
            console.log({err: null, stats: stats});
            template.externalData.set({err: null, stat: stats});
        }
    });
};
// }); //comment the above line and use this, if you used onCreated instead of created.
```

Then in your helpers,

```
Template.profile.helpers({
    externalData: function () {
        var template = Template.instance();
        return template.externalData.get();
    }
});
```

Then in your template html,

```
<template name="profile">
    {{#if externalData}}
        {{#if externalData.err}}
            <p>There is an error. {{externalData.err}}</p>
        {{else}}
            <ul>
                {{#each externalData.stats}}
                    <li>{{name}} - {{value}}</li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
         {{/if}}
     {{/if}}
</template>
```

Comment: Did test this quickly, both with Session and ReactiveVar, both didnt want to work...

Comment: @cschaeffler What happened when you use them? Any error messages in the console? Or is it no error and nothing rendered on template? Add console logs in your helper and Meteor.call's callback and let me know what is being logged.

Comment: Well, nothing rendered on template. I switched to sync callback on meteor server side and hoped it would fix it, however didnt change anything at all. Client console logs result as intended, server console doesnt show issues and intended data, but nothing getting rendered on template...